# Dotted Circle (U+25CC) with Combining Ring (U+030A) drawing incorrectly with XeLaTeX and Courier New

Tags: xetex, unicode

The Dotted Circle `U+25CC` with Combining Ring `U+030A` is not rendering correctly in my XeLaTeX document.  They should be drawn together as one character, but instead are drawn separately as two characters.  Oddly enough, the Latin Lowercase 'a' `U+0061` with combining ring *does* render correctly.

I noticed that this problem occurs with `Courier New`, but not `Times New Roman`.  I thought it might be a font issue, but then I added the characters to a blank document in TextEdit (I'm on macOS) and they both draw correctly with both fonts.  I'm not sure what's causing it to misrender with XeLaTeX and `Courier New`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[pagesize=pdftex]{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
% \setromanfont{Times New Roman} % 'Times New Roman' works, but 'Courier New' doesn't. Why?
\setromanfont{Courier New}
\begin{document}
å % U+0061 U+030A (Latin Lowercase 'a' with Combining Ring)
◌̊ % U+25CC U+030A (Dotted Circle with Combining Ring)
\end{document}
```

This is how they render with `Courier New` in TextEdit on macOS (correct):

[image]

This is how they render with `Courier New` in XeLaTeX (incorrect):

[image]

Comment: If all other remedies fail, you can use the `stackengine` package and then `\stackengine{1pt}{\symbol{"25CC}}{\symbol{"030A}}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thank you, that does work, but would there be an easy way to instruct XeLaTeX to automatically replace the character sequence with your workaround without having to modify the text itself?

Comment: That's quite strange, because U+25CC is supposed to be a dummy character to show the positioning of combining accents, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_circle

Comment: I have a very old version of Courier New (2.82) which renders `U+25CC U+030A` as two boxes (i.e., like missing glyphs) on top of each other. `U+0061 U+030A` is correct. Could there be two different versions of the font lying around and XeTeX is picking up the wrong one? (Different font versions do give me different output, but I didn't try very hard to find a working one. Weirdly, v6.92 stacks things right and has the Dotted Circle, but shows boxes instead of the ring above in both cases. Beats me.)